# Unity 2D Game - Making rigidbodies fly in a straight line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I want to create a 2D game and for that i need to create a number of rigidbodies 2D that fly in a constant speed without stopping (at least for the start). I created an array of GameObjects and everythink was good (I also created a bounds check).

My problem is that I gave every gameobject an equal velocity that remains equal (every fixedupdate), but for some reason they do not keep moving in a straight line (one gameobject is getting closer to another and away from another gameobject etc).

Here is the physics code:

```
private void FixedUpdate(){
    if (ballsAreMoving) {
        foreach(GameObject ball in balls){
            ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.normalized * ballSpeed;
        }
    }

}

IEnumerator FireBalls() {
    foreach(GameObject ball in balls){
        ////////////////Create ball
        ball.transform.position = transform.position;
        ball.SetActive(true);

        ////////////////Realese ball
        ball.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = (new Vector2(lineDirection, 10) * ballSpeed);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootDelay);// Delay
    }
}
```

The FireBalls function is called once after the balls are created and the ballsAreMoving bool is true after FireBalls is called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are applying the velocity to each ball by using the rigidbody's 'velocity' property which is the velocity relative to the local orientation of the gameobject itself, instead you want to apply the velocity relative to the global space of all the balls - "world space". Also, the ball itself _is_ a GameObject, so you do not need to use `ball.gameObject`. With this in mind, if you instead use `ball.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().AddForce(/* insert Vector2 here */, ForceMode2D.Velocity);` does this apply the velocity in the correct manner? If so I'll add this as a proper answer.

Comment: In my previous comment I mistakenly used `ForceMode2D.Velocity` (which I actually meant to be `ForceMode2D.VelocityChange`) however this doesn't exist for ForceMode2D. So, instead try locking the rotation of the balls by using `ball.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().freezeRotation = true;` at the point when the ball is created. Or by doing a little vector calculation to get the velocity you want relative to the world-space coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ill try that and replay how it works.

Comment: I tried what you said and still stays the same with setting the velocity. Using addForce doesnt work because when ever a ball hits the wall it does not return. Maybe there is another force set?

Comment: Do you actually want the balls to move independently? Or should they all move simultaneously no matter what? What happens if a ball collides with something?

Comment: Yes. I want them to move with physics in the screen, in the screen bounds and collide with obsacles

Comment: you could - in that case - make all the balls as children of a gameobject with no collider, then, rather than applying the velocity to each ball, just apply the velocity once to the parent object. With this setup all the balls will follow the parent's position and velocity, but also have their own position/velocity relative to the parent which will become apparent as/if they collide with anything.